# How do I install PortAudio library on Google Colab?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, portaudio

I want to install the PortAudio library on Google Colab to link it to code for recording with a laptop microphone.
How do I install it?

Answer (score 0):

portaudio is not a Python package, it's a C library that's entirely independent of Python, so you can't install it via pip.

See the [portaudio](http://portaudio.com/) for website for details on the official way to get it and install it on your platform.

Does pyaudio not works for you ??

Answer (score 0):

To install PortAudio library in your Colab space:

`!sudo apt-get install libportaudio2`

Hope it helps.